# Python insert variable to mysql via mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create one python script to insert data into mysql, but I got an error when I try to test it.

This is how I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE aaa (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     data CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This is my python script:

```
import mysql.connector
from time import strftime, gmtime, sleep

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='root', password='abcd', database='test_db'
    )
cur = cnx.cursor()
# get current timestamp
curr_time = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", gmtime())
cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO aaa(data) VALUES (%s)", (curr_time)
            )
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

The error is like this:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: you forget `%` in  `"INSERT INTO aaa(data) VALUES (%s)", (curr_time)` it should be `"INSERT INTO aaa(data) VALUES (%s)"%(curr_time)`

Comment: `(curr_time)` -> `(curr_time,)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace `,` with `%` in  `"INSERT INTO aaa(data) VALUES (%s)", (curr_time)` it should be `"INSERT INTO aaa(data) VALUES (%s)"%(curr_time)`.
@tsh is correct use this `(curr_time) -> (curr_time,)` instead